# hex конвертирует int в str вместо int

Tags: python, строки, hex, int

Вот код:

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frk1/hazedumper/master/csgo.json'
print('updating offsets')
response = requests.get(url).json()
dwLocalPlayer = hex(response["signatures"]["dwClientState_GetLocalPlayer"])
print(type(dwLocalPlayer))
```

выводит `<class 'str'>.` Но обычные переменные с 16-ричным кодом выводят `<class 'int'>`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как справиться с этии?

Чтобы прочитать кусок памяти процесса, необходимо установить адрес, который состоит также из смещения(dwLocalPlayer), но мне не удается сложить int+str.
Если сделать переменную 0x108, то она будет в интегере, мне необходимо сделать localplayer интегером в 16-ричной системе счисления. Надеюсь, вы поняли меня.

Comment: А оно должно быть int?

Comment: Я выше написал, что если сделать, допустим переменную а = 0x108, тип переменной будет int.

Comment: А что нужно? Чтобы выводило int? Зачем? Или чтобы именно было число, а не строка?

Comment: Функция hex переводит в строку=) в инт она не переведет. Опиши что у тебя в том файле и что хочешь получить из него.

Comment: Дополнил пост, надеюсь вы меня поймете

Comment: @gisi24, префиксы `0x` -- hex, `0b` -- bin, `0o` -- oct, описывают числа, целые числа, т.е. написав в коде `0b1001` вы получите целое число, а не бинарное представление. `UPD.` а чтобы превратить строку в hex в число нужно использовать функцию `int`, например: `int("0xff", 16)`

Comment: Мне нужно превратить число в 16-ричное интегеровое число

Comment: @gisi24, в компьютере целые числа (и не только целые) в двоичном виде хранятся. В другие системы счисления (например, 10-чную, 16-ричную) они преобразовываются только при выводе на экран или при конвертации в строку. Т.е. целое число нельзя преобразовать в 16 вид, так чтобы оно оставалось целым числом.